# spark dataframe replace value with value from other row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df with a lot of columns, but my problem is with 2 columns :

```
val df = Seq(("id1","unknown"),("id1","type1"),("id1","unknown"),("id2","typeX"),
             ("id2","typeX"),("id2","unknown"),("id5","typeY"),("id2","unknown"))
    .toDF("ID","TYPE")
+---+-------+
| ID|   TYPE|
+---+-------+
|id1|unknown|
|id1|  type1|
|id1|unknown|
|id2|  typeX|
|id2|  typeX|
|id2|unknown|
|id5|  typeY|
|id2|unknown|
+---+-------+
```

I want to replace the type "unknown" by the type that corresponds to the ID. 
The results should look like this :

```
+---+-----+
| ID| TYPE|
+---+-----+
|id1|type1|
|id1|type1|
|id1|type1|
|id2|typeX|
|id2|typeX|
|id2|typeX|
|id5|typeY|
|id2|typeX|
+---+-----+
```

It cannot be hard coded (with a `when id1 -> type1` etc) because i have 300 000 IDs that change every week...

Here is what I have already tried:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("ID")

df.withColumn("TYPE",collect_list("TYPE").over(w))

+---+--------------------------------+
|ID |TYPE                            |
+---+--------------------------------+
|id5|[typeY]                         |
|id1|[unknown, type1, unknown]       |
|id1|[unknown, type1, unknown]       |
|id1|[unknown, type1, unknown]       |
|id2|[typeX, typeX, unknown, unknown]|
|id2|[typeX, typeX, unknown, unknown]|
|id2|[typeX, typeX, unknown, unknown]|
|id2|[typeX, typeX, unknown, unknown]|
+---+--------------------------------+

df.withColumn("TYPE",typeProcessingUDF(col("TYPE")))

+---+-----+
| ID| TYPE|
+---+-----+
|id5|typeY|
|id1|type1|
|id1|type1|
|id1|type1|
|id2|typeX|
|id2|typeX|
|id2|typeX|
|id2|typeX|
+---+-----+

def dtypeProcessing(dtypeList : mutable.WrappedArray[String]) : String = {
    val dtype = dtypeList
        .filter(element => element!= "unknown" && element!="")
        .distinct
    dtype.length match {
        case 0 => "Unknown"
        case x if x >1 => "Unknown"
        case x if x ==1 => dtype(0)
    }
}
val typeProcessingUDF = udf(dtypeProcessing _)
```

This works,

But it doesn't process all situations considering the cases :

- `if [type1,type2] => return "Unknown"`
- `if [type1,type2,type2] => return type2`

Comment: What do you want to do when a certain id has more than one type? Or no type at all except for unknown?

Comment: if more than on type,return the dominant type. If no type return "Unknown"

Comment: What does 'dominant' mean?

Comment: sorry, the most represented type for the ID, if for id1 : [type1,type2,type2,"unknown"], it would be type2

Comment: And what about [id1=>type1,type2,unknown]? It seems that you haven't thought this through...

Comment: if [type1,type2] return Unknown. 
I add what i tries so far. 
It works fine, i just miss the case [type1,type1,type2] ...

Answer (score -1):

With window by "ID", and function "first" with ignored nulls:

```
val idWindow = Window.partitionBy("ID")
val unknownToNull = when($"TYPE" === "unknown", null).otherwise($"TYPE")
val result = df.withColumn("TYPE",
  coalesce(unknownToNull,
    first(unknownToNull, ignoreNulls = true).over(idWindow)
  )
)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+
|ID |TYPE |
+---+-----+
|id1|type1|
|id1|type1|
|id1|type1|
|id2|typeX|
|id2|typeX|
|id2|typeX|
|id2|typeX|
|id5|typeY|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: That, too, ignores the case of val df = Seq(("id1","unknown"),("id1","type1"),("id1","type2"),("id1","type2"),("id1","unknown"),("id2","typeX"),
      ("id2","typeX"),("id2","unknown"),("id5","typeY"),("id2","unknown"))        id1 will get type1 as TYPE while it needs to get type2 (dominant type)

Comment: This case was not specified in question, but answer was updated for take such case into account.